# SQL запрос из 3-х таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Структура БД]

Второй раз пытаюсь получить ответ на cвой вопрос:
Выше приведена структура базы. Опишу все подробно:
Первая таблица это сигнализации, в которой есть лишь `id`, `firma` и `model`. Здесь все понятно. Дальше идет таблица `costusers` - здесь хранятся данные о стоимости каждой сигнализации в разных магазинах, т.е. в поле `id_sign` хранится `id` из таблицы `signalizacii`, дальше поле `id_user` - это поле которое ссылается на поле `uc_id` в таблице `uc1`, и поле `cost` - это цена. 
Таблица `uc1` - это все магазины во всех городах.

Нужно просто выбрать все сигнализации из таблицы `signalizacii` и добавить еще одно поле в котором будет хранить минимальная цена для конкретного города. Если вдруг случается так что в таблице `costusers` нет ни одной цены на какую-то сигнализацию в некотором городе, то нужно вывести 0.

Помогите пожалуйста, бьюсь уже несколько дней над этим запросом... SQL не мое...

**Обновление**

```
 select signalizacii.*, COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN costusers.cost != 0 THEN costusers.cost END), 0) 
 from signalizacii 
 left join costusers on id_sign = id 
 left join uc1 on costusers.id_user = uc1.user_id
 where uc1.city = 'Краснодар'
 group by signalizacii.id
```

Вот что я хотел - показалось мне. Но не тут-то было если в таблице costusers не установлена цена на какую-нибудь сигнализацию то эта сигнализация не выводится вообще.

Проблема до сих пор не решена. Прошу помощи... Пожалуйста.
Выше приведенный мной результат к сожалению не выводит сигнализацию вообще если цена на нее не установлена ни одним из магазинов указанного города. А она должна выводится но цена должна быть 0.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что значит "в конкретном городе", он задан изначально в запросе т.е. мы выбираем цены только по конкретному городу. Или надо отдельными строками показать товар-город-цена_в_городе по всем городам в системе ?

Comment: Город указывается изначально в запросе

Comment: Пробуйте `select  signalizacii.*, min(cost), city from  signalizacii left join costusers on id_sign = id left join uc1 on uc_id =  costusers.id_user group by  signalizacii.id, signalizacii.firma, signalizacii.model, city`

Comment: А, если город известен то так select signalizacii.*, min(cost) from signalizacii left join costusers on id_sign = id left join uc1 on uc_id = costusers.id_user  where city = @city group by signalizacii.id, signalizacii.firma, signalizacii.model

Comment: Какую СУБД используете?

Comment: @nick_n_a Если город задан, а условие "показать все товары, даже без цен" сохраняется, то условие по городу надо поместить в `on` для uc1

Comment: @nick_n_a, так как автору, видимо, лень, сделаю это за него: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db733/1/0. Там сразу приведён ваш запрос. Думаю, надо ещё добавить проверку на `null`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SQL запрос сложный](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602482/sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9)

Comment: точно, isnull вылетело с головы, (есть аналог coalesce - оно в 99% СУБД работает). надо вместо `min(cost)`, а `coalesce(min(cost),0)` либо `isnull(min(cost),0)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Но пока ничего не помогло. Версия СУБД MySQL 5.5.25.

Comment: Column 'cost' in field list is ambiguous - возникает эта ошибка во всех приведенных Вами примерах

Comment: select * from signalizacii as s join costusers as c on s.id = c.id_sign where c.cost in (select COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN cost != 0 THEN cost END), 0) from costusers where costusers.id_user in (select user_id from uc1 where city = '".$city."') and costusers.id_sign = s.id ) and s.firma = 'StarLine' GROUP BY s.id

Comment: Вот рабочий запрос за исключением того что он не выводит сигнализации если на них не установлены цены в указанном городе, а должен выводить, но цену писать 0

Comment: Покажите дамп БД с примерном данных. Или хотя бы `CREATE TABLE...` для таблиц. Будьте снисходительны!

Answer (score 3):

Как я понял, нужно выбрать минимальные цены для всех товаров во всех магазинах, даже если таковые не заданы. Как вариант, можно использовать такой запрос, основанный на том, что предложил уважаемый [nick_n_a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17974/nick-n-a):

```
SELECT signalizacii.*, name, coalesce(MIN(cost), 0) FROM uc1
JOIN signalizacii
LEFT JOIN costusers ON costusers.id_user = uc_id
AND costusers.id_sign = id
GROUP BY name, model
```

Рабочий пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9294/1/0

**С отбором по городу:**

```
SELECT signalizacii.*, name, coalesce(MIN(cost), 0) FROM uc1
JOIN signalizacii
LEFT JOIN costusers ON costusers.id_user = uc_id
AND costusers.id_sign = id
WHERE city='Краснодар'
GROUP BY name, model
```

Comment: Почти то что нужно, НО нужно выбрать сигнализации для конкретного города, например Москва, т.е город задается в самом запросе...

Comment: @Александр, так добавьте простое условие `WHERE uc_id = 'id нужного города'` перед `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Че-то не так... везде нули выводит хотя это не так....((((((

Comment: select signalizacii.*, coalesce(min(costusers.cost),0) from signalizacii 
left join costusers on id_sign = id 
left join uc1 on uc_id = costusers.id_user 
and costusers.id_user =  uc1.user_id where uc1.city = 'Краснодар' group by signalizacii.id

Comment: Не могу найти ошибку.... пустой результат((((

Comment: @Александр, просто к приведённому мной запросу надо было добавить нормальное условие:
`SELECT signalizacii.*, name, coalesce(MIN(cost), 0) FROM uc1
JOIN signalizacii
LEFT JOIN costusers ON costusers.id_user = uc_id
AND costusers.id_sign = id
WHERE city='Краснодар'
GROUP BY name, model`

Answer (score 2):

Не пытаетесь ли вы убить одним камнем двух зайцев? Зачем вообще так нужно все сделать одним SQL запросом? Чего вы этим достигните?

Наверняка список сигнализаций у вас более-менее фиксирован, то есть не меняется каждую секунду. А значит вы можете загрузить одним запросом список всех сигнализаций, сохранить этот список в кеше в нужном порядке. Затем, по мере необходимости, запрашивать цены для какого-то города, при визуализации подставляя в колонку цены по каждой сигнализации.

Подумайте еще так: не столько важно сделать все в один запрос, сколько важно чтобы вы сами смогли понять что тут делается через год или два, когда понадобится очень срочно исправить какой-то баг. В одном случае вы сразу сходу разберетесь что к чему, потратив на исправление 10 минут. В другом случае вы потратите час или два чтобы восстановить ход мысли и вспомнить все хаки, использованные при написании запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Много LEFT JOIN-ов, лучше бы нулевые цены отдельным UNION-ом сделать, а в остальном работает как просили.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*, ISNULL(m.mincost, 0) AS 'mincost'
FROM #signal_signalizacii s
    LEFT JOIN #signal_costusers u ON u.id_sign = s.id
    LEFT JOIN #signal_uc1 c ON u.[user_id] = c.uc_id AND c.city = 'Краснодар'
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MIN(cost) AS 'mincost' FROM #signal_costusers
        WHERE id_sign = s.id
            AND [user_id] = c.uc_id
            AND c.uc_id IS NOT NULL
        ) m
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете уточнить все таки в какой базе данных выполняется запрос? это Mysql Oracle PostGre или MsSql

Будь это Oracle, можно было бы использовать аналитические функции : http://www.sql.ru/blogs/oracleandsql/1926, конструкция

```
MIN(cost) OVER(Partition BY city)
```

работает именно так как вам нужно. Если уточните бд можно будет искать реализацию схожую с аналитическими функциями в Oracle

Простите не заметил что это Mysql, тогда прошу проверить:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0de13/11

с нулами сами разберетесь тогда на что их заменить:

```
/*
все сигнализации из таблицы signalizacii */
SELECT s.*
  FROM signalizacii s ;

/*
и добавить минимальную цену по городу, т.е. добавляем поле 
Город

min_cost_s_c - минимальная цена на сигнализацию по городу
*/
SELECT s.*, u.city, min(c.cost) as min_cost_s_c
  FROM signalizacii s 
  left join costusers c ON s.id = c.id_sign
  left join uc1 u ON c.id_user = u.user_id
group by s.id, s.firma, s.model, u.city;
/*
если нужна минимальная цена по городу не зависимо от сигнализации, 
просто минимальная цена то делаем так
*/
SELECT s.*, t.city, t.cost
  FROM signalizacii s 
  left join ( select     u.city, 
                     min(c.cost) as cost, 
                     max(c.id_sign) as id_sign
                from costusers c 
                left join uc1 u ON c.id_user = u.user_id
             GROUP BY u.city)  t 
          ON s.id = t.id_sign;
```

или если смущает max(c.id_sign) то можно попробовать по другому

```
/*
если нужна минимальная цена по городу не зависимо от сигнализации, 
просто минимальная цена то делаем так
*/
SELECT s.*, t.city, t.cost
  FROM signalizacii s 
  left join ( select     u.city, 
                     min(c.cost) as cost, 
                     group_concat(c.id_sign) as id_sign
                from costusers c 
                left join uc1 u ON c.id_user = u.user_id
             GROUP BY u.city)  t 
          ON s.id IN (t.id_sign);
```

Comment: У вопроса имеется тег MySQL. Так что это вряд ли Oracle...

Comment: точно. тогда прошу проверить http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0de13/11

Comment: @Akina первоначально тега mysql не было. добавил его я, взяв информацию из комментария под вопросом

Answer (score 0):

```
 left join uc1 on costusers.id_user = uc1.user_id
 where uc1.city = 'Краснодар'
```

Это такой способ незаметно написать `inner join`, возможно попутно сбить с толку и оптимизатор запроса. `Left join` в случае если строка не найдена использует для всех полей `NULL`. `NULL` ничему не может быть равен, даже самому себе. Поэтому сравнение с константной строкой не даёт `true` и целиком эта строка отбрасывается. Что превращает запрос в `inner join`.

Необходимо или учитывать возможность появления NULL явно

```
 left join uc1 on costusers.id_user = uc1.user_id
 where (uc1.city is null or uc1.city = 'Краснодар')
```

Или, что обычно нагляднее, перенести условие поиска в условие объединения:

```
 left join uc1 on costusers.id_user = uc1.user_id and uc1.city = 'Краснодар'
 -- where при этом уже не нужен
```

---

### В итоге

Получение всех строк из таблицы со странным названием `signalizacii` и добавлением минимального предложения стоимости в выбранном городе

```
 select signalizacii.*, COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN costusers.cost != 0 THEN costusers.cost END), 0) 
 from signalizacii 
 left join costusers on id_sign = id 
 left join uc1 on costusers.id_user = uc1.user_id and uc1.city = 'Краснодар'
 group by signalizacii.id
```

Или можно переписать запрос вот так:

```
select signalizacii.*, COALESCE(mincost, 0) 
from signalizacii 
left join (
     select id_sign, min(costusers.cost) as mincost
         from costusers
             join uc1 using(id_user)
         where uc1.city = 'Краснодар'
             and costusers.cost > 0 -- исходно у вас != 0, наверное логичнее > 0?
         group by id_sign
) m ON id = id_sign
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь на здоровье )

```
select 
       s.*, 
       IF(costs.minCost is null, 0, costs.minCost) as minCost
FROM signalizacii s 
LEFT JOIN (select 
                 min(cost) as minCost, 
                 c.id_sign 
          FROM costusers c 
          LEFT JOIN uc1 ON c.id_user = uc1.uc_id 
          WHERE city = "BAKU" 
          GROUP BY c.id_sign) costs ON s.id = costs.id_sign
```